# AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider.credentialsWithRegionType is depreacted. What to use instead?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm AWS Cognito and AWSCognitoDataset in an iOS app.

I'm calling registerCognitoWithConfiguration() but this has been deprecated.
Instead an init() should be used. But the one I think I need to use requires a identityId which I don't have access to until I use a credentialsProvider to call getIdentityId() - this is a catch 22.

So, how can I replace registerCognitoWithConfiguration()?

```
Digits.sharedInstance().authenticateWithViewController( ...
{session, error in
if session != nil {
    self.completeDigitsLogin()
} else {
    ...
}

func completeDigitsLogin() {
    if let session = Digits.sharedInstance().session() {
        AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider.credentialsWithRegionType(
            Constants.COGNITO_REGIONTYPE,
            accountId:Constants.AWS_ACCOUNT_ID,
            identityPoolId:Constants.COGNITO_IDENTITY_POOL_ID,
            unauthRoleArn:"",
            authRoleArn:Constants.COGNITO_ARN_AUTH_ROLE,
            logins:["www.digits.com": makeTwitterSessionString(session)])

        let conf = AWSServiceConfiguration(
            region:Constants.COGNITO_REGIONTYPE,
            credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider)

        AWSCognito.registerCognitoWithConfiguration(config, forKey:"main")

        credentialsProvider.getIdentityId().continueWithBlock {
            (task:AWSTask!) -> AnyObject! in

           let cognitoId = task.result as! String
           print("CognitoId = \(cognitoId)")

           let cognitoSync = AWSCognito(forKey:"main")
           self.dataset = cognitoSync.openOrCreateDataset("Candidate")
           self.dataset.setString(session.phoneNumber, forKey:"phone")
           self.synchronizeDataset()
        return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It does not seem that registerCognitoWithConfiguration() is deprecated.

https://github.com/aws/amazon-cognito-ios/blob/master/Cognito/AWSCognitoService.m#L118

https://github.com/aws/amazon-cognito-ios/blob/master/Cognito/AWSCognitoService.h#L232

Comment: Xcode states it is. I'll stick with the API for now.